# ChartJS - Donut charts with multiple rings

Tags: javascript, chart.js, donut-chart

Is it possible to create a donut chart with multiple rings using ChartJS as shown below?

[image: multi series donut chart]

Comment: It seems that this is not possible. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28806808/chartjs-nested-pie-doughnut-charts

Comment: Have you get any solution? I also need same thing

Comment: @iWatch nope. We changed to D3 chart http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29301151/d3-js-donut-charts-with-multiple-rings-and-animation-transition

Comment: @SoniAli Thanks for your answer...But yes it is possible to make nested doughnut with chartJS...I made it...:)

Comment: @iWatch can you please share the answer!

Answer (score 20):

You can find out the solution at [fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/zuupzpLL/)

```
var ctx = document.getElementById("chart-area").getContext("2d");
var myDoughnut = new Chart(ctx, config);
var config = {
    type: 'doughnut',
    data: {
        datasets: [{
            data: [
               10,20,30
                ],
                backgroundColor: [
                "#F7464A",
                "#46BFBD",
                "#FDB45C"
            ],
        }, {
            data: [
                randomScalingFactor(),
                randomScalingFactor(),
                randomScalingFactor()

            ],
                backgroundColor: [
                "#F7464A",
                "#46BFBD",
                "#FDB45C"
            ],
        }],
        labels: [
            "Red",
            "Green",
            "Yellow"
        ]
    },
    options: {
        responsive: true
    }
};
```

Comment: This is awesome!! :D

Comment: How to remove white stroke except in the part of separation of the inner and outer chart?

Comment: is there an way we can make rings interdependent? like in outer ring i need 4 sections and all of them have 2 subsections each!

Answer (score 4):

You need to add multiple datasets into chart. they will be displayed as you need. Please look into their own [sample](http://www.chartjs.org/samples/latest/charts/pie.html) of pie chart. You can download and open it locally as example. There they have multiple datasets, that makes chart look like you need.

Hope that it helped.

Comment: The correct sample link is this: http://www.chartjs.org/samples/latest/charts/pie.html

Answer (score 0):

I know it was old question, but have stuck yesterday into same, so far best that i have touch is Chart js and this is a [plugin](https://chartjs-plugin-datalabels.netlify.app/samples/charts/doughnut.html) who does exactly that (and even more!)

Answer (score 0):

[image]

In the 'data' field, we add more charts by adding elements for the 'datasets' array.

```
data: {
  labels: [], // Label of Legends and Slices on Doughnut Chart.
  datasets: [
    {
      data: [], // Doughnut Chart data.
      backgroundColor: [], // Color of Slices on Doughnut Chart.
      ...
    }
  ]
};
```

```js
Chart.register(ChartDataLabels);

// Write Javascript code!
var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart');
var data = {
  // labels: ['Red', 'Orange', 'Yellow', 'Green', 'Blue'],
  datasets: [
    {
      data: [20, 20, 50, 70, 80],
      backgroundColor: ['#FFC300', '#F72585', '#4CC9F0', '#5ED400', '#4D09E8'],
    },
    {
      data: [90, 30, 60, 40, 20],
      backgroundColor: ['#FFC300', '#F72585', '#4CC9F0', '#5ED400', '#4D09E8'],
    },
  ],
};

var options = {
  responsive: true,
  plugins: {
    datalabels: {
      color: 'white',
      font: {
        weight: 'bold',
      },
    },
  },
};

var myDoughnutChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'doughnut',
  data,
  options,
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@3.0.0/dist/chart.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-plugin-datalabels@2.0.0"></script>
<canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
```

[An example of adding and removing rings in ChartJS with buttons.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-x6vsmq?file=index.js)

[image]