# Chart.js labels specific to each nested dataset

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I have a nested donut chart, very similar to the one given by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28806808/chartjs-nested-pie-doughnut-charts).

If you look at the segment labels when you hover over them, however, you will see that the last three segments of the inner circle are 'undefined'. I have found that the labels that you pass in are applied to every dataset. This works fine if you have the same number of segments at each level, which I do not.

I have tried just adding more labels to the `labels` array, however this does not work. I have also tried adding a `label` array inside each dataset (I saw this on the ChartJS Gitbook), however this does not change what is displayed either.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
var chartData = {
  labels: [
    "Red",
    "Blue",
    "Yellow"
  ],
  datasets: [{
    data: [300, 50, 100],
    backgroundColor: [
      "#FF6384",
      "#36A2EB",
      "#FFCE56"
    ],
    hoverBackgroundColor: [
      "#FF6384",
      "#36A2EB",
      "#FFCE56"
    ]
  }, {
    data: [200, 100, 25, 25, 66, 34],
    backgroundColor: [
      "#FF6384",
      "#36A2EB",
      "#FFCE56",
      "#FF6384",
      "#36A2EB",
      "#FFCE56"
    ],
    hoverBackgroundColor: [
      "#FF6384",
      "#36A2EB",
      "#FFCE56",
      "#FF6384",
      "#36A2EB",
      "#FFCE56"
    ]
      }]
};
var pieChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'pie',
  data: chartData
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.3.0/Chart.min.js"></script>

<canvas id="myChart" width="300" height="300"></canvas>
```

Comment: Does this help? https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/1417

Comment: I've just got it! Thanks @mkaatman, I'd seen that earlier but had no idea how to implement it. After a looot of trial and error finally got it working. :)